# Rails 7 can't get database password from env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, environment-variables

I have my rails 7.0.4.3 app with the usual database.yaml conf:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 10
  postgis_schema: public
  schema_search_path: public,postgresql
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_HOST") { "localhost" } %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PORT") { 5432 } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_USERNAME") { %x(whoami).strip } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD") { "password" } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  username: 'postgres'
  password: 'password'
  database: <%= "#{ENV['PROJECT_NAME']}_development" %>

test:
  <<: *default
  username: 'postgres'
  password: 'password'
  database: <%= "#{ENV['PROJECT_NAME']}_test" %>

staging:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= "#{ENV['PROJECT_NAME']}_staging" %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= "#{ENV['PROJECT_NAME']}_production" %>

dev_remote:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= "#{ENV['PROJECT_NAME']}_dev_remote" %>
```

The app is running in docker on a remote server.
When starting up it gives me this error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server at "REDACTED", port 5438 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server at "REDACTED", port 5438 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If I try to fetch the env `DATABASE_PASSWORD` it is correctly set, both in container console and in `rails c`.

The output of `Rails.configuration.database_configuration` is this one:

```
=> 
{"default"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"user"},
 "development"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"password", "database"=>"project_development"},
 "test"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"password", "database"=>"project_test"},
 "staging"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"user", "database"=>"project_staging"},
 "production"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"user", "database"=>"project_production"},
 
"dev_remote"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "postgis_schema"=>"public", "schema_search_path"=>"public,postgresql", "host"=>"REDACTED", "port"=>5438, "username"=>"user", "database"=>"project_dev_remote", "password"=>nil}}
```

`"password"=>nil` no matter how i set it.
Is there a way to figure this out?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.4-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash build-base postgresql-dev tzdata git openssh ssmtp nano

WORKDIR /myapp
ENV RAILS_ENV $RAILS_ENV

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.2.32 && bundle config set --local without 'development test' && bundle install -j $(nproc)

COPY . /myapp

RUN chmod +x /myapp/start-app.sh
CMD /myapp/start-app.sh
```

Comment: Do you really need this? You can just set `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` and override any setting from the YAML file. No extra config, no fuss.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: Can you post you Dockerfile? My guess would be that your application is running as a different user than the one where you did set up the environment variables, but on the other hand you shouldn't be able to access the other variables either...

Comment: @max if i set `password: ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"]` without erb, then it is read as a string --> `"password"=>"ENV[\"DATABASE_PASSWORD\"]"`.

@BenjaminScharbau Dockerfile is in the op. But as you said, the only env var to have this problem is password.

Comment: @max with DATABASE_URL I have the same issue. DATABASE_PASSWORD is nil

Comment: @Vi. You of course need to actually construct a URL as per the guide

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau @max I found the issue! It was an ambiguous `@` character in the password 